# Where can I find BIOS files for flashing it with a chip programmer?

Tags: motherboard, bios

I have a laptop (Fujitsu AH532).
It stuck in POST process and doesn't go for booting a device.
I'm sure this is BIOS problem.
So I need to flash my bios. I can't do that with provided bios driver in Fujitsu website because my computer doesn't boot.
So I want to pop up the bios chip out of the motherboard and pop it to a chip programmer and reprogram it and pop it back to the motherboard again.
The problem is I haven't bios files. As you know the provided bios update files are executable files and need an operating system to run.

How can I find associated files to flash my bios chip with a chip programmer?

Comment: This looks like a classic [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me

Comment: @Tetsujin This is not a XY problem, because I know exactly how to do X solution, but I explained it in a way that others can understand the situation. Actually I consulted this solution with a professional repairman and he came up with it. By the way if you know the Y solution, appreciated to share it with me ;)

Comment: The chip isn't just something you "pop out" on these types of devices, nor are they, something you just hook up to a programmer.  There is normally a DOS-based program which comes with a non-executable, even that file, woudln't be compatible with what you want though.

Comment: Most laptops have a "crisis recovery" procedure to flash the bios even when they won't post (bricked). This is usually a manufacturer secret on how to do this but occasionally its gets leaked, do some research.

Answer (score 1):

## The first and obvious question I have to ask is:

Are you sure that the actual BIOS ROM is corrupt and not just the CMOS memory? Have you tried resetting CMOS? There should be a jumper on the motherboard (I assume you have the ability to open the chassis as you're going to pry out the BIOS chip). If you can't find the jumper there should be a round batter that powers the CMOS memory if you remove the CMOS battery, disconnect the AC power and disconnect the system battery and let it sit for a few minutes it should clear. Some manufacturers recommend pressing the power button for 30 seconds to drain any remaining current from capacitors on the motherboard.

The procedure may vary, consult your system manual.

## Now it that doesn't help:

The BIOS update program must in some way contain the actual image written to the chip. You can look at the files in the update (extract any archives and cab files etc) and see if you can determine which file it is. If this comes up empty you can ask the Fujitsu support if they can provide it for you.

In any case if you have a programmer, then make a backup of the original ROM first. Now if you have the original ROM it should be a lot easier to determine the correct file to flash by looking at file sizes and hex-diffs. (If you don't know how to do this, then you have no business trying to program the BIOS chip).

I find it unlikely that the BIOS (EEP)ROM will corrupt itself without external factors. How did you brick it? Botched update?

Comment: I tried resetting the CMOS but didn't fix the issue. I will let you know about other approaches. And abut the the reason of this problem, I really don't know!!! Maybe its a bios virus.

Comment: @Ham3d - A BIOS virus wouldn't prevent a POST, the entire point of a virus like that, is to infect the target computer and collect information.

Comment: @Ramhound unless the virus botched it's infection... but I agree BIOS viruses are rare.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree, a BIOS virus wouldn't prevent a POST process but it can corrupt the BIOS and it can effect the POST.

Comment: @Ham3d - If your BIOS was infected you should be able to file additional vectors on the HDD.  All I know evidence you supplied simply points to a corrupt BIOS at most, there is zero evidence, it was caused by a virus.  I called out that statement because, bad speculation without any evidence, is not helpful.

Answer (score -1):

[This might help.](http://www.linlap.com/fujitsu_lifebook_ah532) Make sure to read the comment, seems that something wrong with NVRAM/UEFI settings and you might be able to fix it without reflashing BIOS.

Comment: Websites have been known to go down. Could you add the essential parts of the answer to your answer, rather than purely relying on the link?